# Как установить картинки для родительских списков

Tags: php, css

Ребят как можно в этот скрипт вставить картинки? У меня 6 родительских категорий и у каждого родителя своя картинка должна быть. Это мой весь код категории, конечно же без стилей

```html
<?php
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT `id`, `parent_id`, `name` FROM `category`"); 
$cats = array();
while($cat =  mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    $cats[$cat['parent_id']][] =  $cat;
function create_tree ($cats,$parent_id){
    if(is_array($cats) and  isset($cats[$parent_id])){
        $tree = !$parent_id?'':'<ul>';
        foreach($cats[$parent_id] as $cat){
           $tree .= "<li>";
           $tree .= !isset($cats[$cat['id']])?"<a href='view_cat.php?cat=".$cat['id']."'>".$cat['name']."</a>":"<span>".$cat['name']."</span>";
           $tree .=  create_tree($cats,$cat['id']);
           $tree .= '</li>';         
        }
        $tree .= !$parent_id?'':'</ul>';
    }else return null;          
return !$parent_id?'<ul class="sublist">'.$tree.'</ul>':$tree;        
} 
echo create_tree($cats, 0);
```

Вот пример как надо

[image: категории]

Comment: Пробовали добавлять тэг `img` перед `a` и `span`?

Comment: @Arnial у меня 6 родительских категорий, для каждой категории своя картинка. А этот код выводит всю мою таблицу. То что вы мне предложили как я понял, то 1 и та же картинка показывается

Comment: Извените ошибся, `img` нужен перед `ul`. Для того чтоб они были разными подставляйте разный `src` в картинки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT `id`, `parent_id`, `name` FROM `category`"); 
$cats = array();
while($cat =  mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    $cats[$cat['parent_id']][] =  $cat;
function create_tree ($cats,$parent_id){
    if(is_array($cats) and  isset($cats[$parent_id])){
        $tree = !$parent_id?'':'<ul>';
        foreach($cats[$parent_id] as $cat){
          $tree .= "<li>";
          $img = !$parent_id?'<img src="images/'.$cat['name'].'.png">':'';
          $tree .= !isset($cats[$cat['id']])?"<a href='view_cat.php?cat=".$cat['id']."'>".$img." ".$cat['name']."</a>":"<span>".$img." ".$cat['name']."</span>";
          $tree .=  create_tree($cats,$cat['id']);
          $tree .= '</li>';         
        }
        $tree .= !$parent_id?'':'</ul>';
    }else return null;          
return !$parent_id?'<ul class="sublist">'.$tree.'</ul>':$tree;        
} 
echo create_tree($cats, 0);
?>
```

Comment: вы меня выручаете по полной спасибо вам) а не могли бы подсказать как их подключить? надо в бд добавить картинки или как?до этого я делал так <img src="images/things.png" id="things-images">Вещи</a> и к другим спискам применял так же, а тут не знаю:)

Comment: обновил код. должно работать

Comment: спасибо)))) + вам за работу:)

Comment: вы бы не могли вот это глянуть) http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/570829/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5/570835?noredirect=1#comment749415_570835