# Как перехватить переменные?

Tags: php, mysql

Ребят почему я не могу перехватить переменные cat, чтобы отображать товары по категориям

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

создал view_cat.php туда внес всю страницу index.php. И пытаюсь перехватить вот таким скриптом

```
<br>
<?php 
session_start();
    include ("include/config.php");
    include ("functions/functions.php");
$cat = clear_string($_GET['cat']);
?>
<?php
    if (!empty($cat))
        {
            $querycat = "AND name='$cat'";
        }

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_products WHERE $filtering $querycat ORDER BY $sorting",$connect)
?>
```

функция очистки строк

```
function clear_string($cl_str) { 
$cl_str = strip_tags($cl_str); 
$cl_str = mysql_real_escape_string($cl_str); 
$cl_str = trim($cl_str); 
return $cl_str; }
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46522/discussion-on-question-by----).

Answer (score 1):

Потому что то значение, которое вы хотите получить лежит тут $_GET['cat']

```
<br>
$cat = $_GET['cat'];
if (!empty($cat))
    {
        $querycat = "AND name='$cat'";
    }else{
        if (!empty($cat))
        {
            $querycat = "";
        }
    }

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_products WHERE $filtering $querycat ORDER BY $sorting",$connect);
```

Comment: Как сделать правильно, не подскажите?

Comment: @Евгений, я предоставил исправленный код, перед первым if добавьте $cat = $_GET['cat'];

Comment: session_start(); include ("include/config.php"); include ("functions/functions.php"); $cat = clear_string($_GET["cat"]); у меня есть гет в начале страницы после подключения configa и functions, но почему то не работает( прошу прощения случайно ваш код исправил

Comment: @tCode а для чего второе условие IF ?

Comment: @webDev_ вы у меня спрашиваете? Спросите у автора

Comment: не углядел, показалось что это была ваша правка.